useEffect for popup modal
I am currently trying to incorporate a popup modal function which I have managed to do and works however, I am trying to now create that same function inside a useEffect hook so that it does not re-render every time. So far, I have tried several methods and nothing seems to work. Here is my code:
AppContent.jsx (without useEffect):
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { X } from 'lucide-react'
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import AppForm from './AppForm';

const AppContent = () => {
    const [ applicationOpen, setApplicationOpen ] = useState(false);
    
    const close = () => setApplicationOpen(false);
    const open = () => setApplicationOpen(true);

  return (
    <>
      <button 
        className='apply-btn'
        onClick={() => applicationOpen ? close() : open()}
      >
        APPLY HERE
      </button>
       
      <AnimatePresence>
        {applicationOpen && <AppForm applicationOpen={applicationOpen} handleClose={close}/>}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  )
}

export default AppContent

The code above works just fine.
AppContent.jsx (with useEffect):
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { X } from 'lucide-react'
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import AppForm from './AppForm';

const AppContent = () => {
    const [ applicationOpen, setApplicationOpen ] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      const close = () => setApplicationOpen(false);
      const open = () => setApplicationOpen(true);

      close();
      open();
    },[]);

  return (
    <>
      <button 
        className='apply-btn'
        onClick={() => applicationOpen ? close() : open()}
      >
        APPLY HERE
      </button>
       
      <AnimatePresence>
        {applicationOpen && <AppForm applicationOpen={applicationOpen} handleClose={close}/>}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  )
}

export default AppContent

Can someone help me please and point out what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

close and open are scoped to your useEffect callback function, they can't be accessed outside of that. Redefining open/close on each render isn't going to hurt your programs performance by very much, I'd suggest leaving it as is, or looking into defining your functions in a reducer or outside your component if you really don't want to redefine them

Sticking with the approach you already have, you can use the useCallback hook to create a function that doesn't re-render every time the application updated
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { X } from 'lucide-react'
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import AppForm from './AppForm';

const AppContent = () => {
    const [ applicationOpen, setApplicationOpen ] = useState(false);
    
    const close = useCallback(() => setApplicationOpen(false),[]);
    const open = useCallback(() => setApplicationOpen(true), []);

  return (
    <>
      <button 
        className='apply-btn'
        onClick={applicationOpen ? close : open}
      >
        APPLY HERE
      </button>
       
      <AnimatePresence>
        {applicationOpen && 
         <AppForm 
           applicationOpen={applicationOpen} 
           handleClose={close}
         />
         }
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  )
}

export default AppContent


There is no problem with the first code you shared. You making AppForm to be conditional is already taking care of that. If not you can move AnimatePresence inside the condition as well. Like this.
return (
  <>
    <button className="apply-btn" onClick={() => (applicationOpen ? close() : open())}>
      APPLY HERE
    </button>

    {applicationOpen && (
      <AnimatePresence>
        <AppForm applicationOpen={applicationOpen} handleClose={close} />
      </AnimatePresence>
    )}
  </>
);

And your usage of useEffect in the second example is completely wrong. Here is how useEffect work. You give two prop to useEffect.

A function
Dependency array

Whenever props or states you give the dependency array changes then function you give is called. It also called at start. Which is when component is mounted.
So your function inside useEffect called at start and it does close the AppForm and then opens it. And because of you defined your open and close functions inside useEffect makes them inaccessible for the outside of it. For more info about useEffect check out the link.
If you want to open the AppForm on start use something like this.
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {X} from 'lucide-react';
import {AnimatePresence} from 'framer-motion';
import AppForm from './AppForm';

const AppContent = () => {
  const [applicationOpen, setApplicationOpen] = useState(false);

  const close = () => setApplicationOpen(false);
  const open = () => setApplicationOpen(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    open();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button className="apply-btn" onClick={() => (applicationOpen ? close() : open())}>
        APPLY HERE
      </button>

      <AnimatePresence>
        {applicationOpen && <AppForm applicationOpen={applicationOpen} handleClose={close} />}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
};

export default AppContent;


thank you for the suggestion. I'm still quite new to useEffects as I haven't really had to use it that often. The reason why I wanted to use useEffect in this instance is because when i first created this function, I got an error message of 'too many re-renders' and I am aware that you can use useEffect to avoid that. Thank you anyway.

That must be because you initially tried to call the close or open function directly on the button onClick. e.g onClick={open()} This will throw the error you mentioned above because  the open function has a state update in it and open() will be called everytime the application re-renders which eventually results in an infinite re-renders.

Can you try moving AnimatePresence inside the condition like in my first code.

Your first code works @irfan çini but it removes the animation that I have set for the AppForm  when you press close so i can't use that method. { AnimationPresence } allows for animation to take effect even when a component is removed from the DOM (which is what happens when you click off a popup).

Your second code was fine however. Thank you as well @Hilory.

The useCallback hook in React memoizes functions to prevent them from being recreated on every render, reducing unnecessary re-renders when dependencies haven't changed.
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { X } from "lucide-react";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import AppForm from "./AppForm";

const AppContent = () => {
  const [applicationOpen, setApplicationOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleAppication = useCallback(() => {
    setApplicationOpen((prev) => !prev);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button className="apply-btn" onClick={toggleAppication}>
        APPLY HERE
      </button>

      <AnimatePresence>
        {applicationOpen && (
          <AppForm applicationOpen={applicationOpen} handleClose={close} />
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </>
  );
};

export default AppContent;


Thank you @Tejas Faldu. This method I have also tried and works. You have to change the value of handleClose to {toggleApplication} as well though.

You can do this even though those functions inside onClick will be re-rendered I think, but they are not really costly:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { X } from 'lucide-react'
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import AppForm from './AppForm';

const AppContent = () => {
    const [applicationOpen, setApplicationOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
           <button 
               className='apply-btn'
               onClick={() => setApplicationOpen((prev) => !prev)}
           >
           APPLY HERE
           </button>
           <AnimatePresence>
              {applicationOpen &&
              <AppForm applicationOpen={applicationOpen}
                  handleClose={() => setApplicationOpen(false)}/>}
           </AnimatePresence>
       </>
    )
}

export default AppContent

